# Enter-Pssession won't connect to server claiming a non-existent parameter (sessionDetails) is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am attempting to connect to a server using a remote PSsession and run a JEA configuration. But when I run the command

```
Enter-PSsession -ComputerName $server -ConfigurationName $config
```

It throws the following error:

```
Enter-PSSession : Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: sessionDetails
```

After examining the PSsession documentation I can't find a parameter named sessionDetails? What is going on?

FURTHER DETAILS:

```
 Enter-PSession $server
```

Connects to the server without error. And when I'm on the server it's self, the command:

```
Enter-PSession -ComputerName localhost -ConfigurationName $config
```

Also enters a PSsession without error. So I'm definitely able to access the server and the configuration definitely works (at least on local host).

Comment: Does your `$config` variable contain a property called sessionDetails? What does the config variable contents look like?

Comment: $config just contains the string 'default' which is the name of the configuration I'm trying to load

Answer (score 0):

Add in your .pssc file a line with TranscriptDirectory = 'xxx'
 
With xxx the folder where audit trail logging will be stored. This will log on the server where you register the JEA script who connected.
In such logging file you can see a line like:
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.10032.0, 6.2.0

This indicates the powershell versions that are supported for the CLIENT side.
In case you are using a client version that is not listed you get that error.

Answer (score -1):

**Enter-PSSession** may not be used correctly by you. Try the below syntax.

Command to start an interactive session with **Server01**, a remote computer. When the session starts, the command prompt changes to include the computer name.

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName Server01
[Server01]: PS C:\>
```

Command to get the PowerShell process and redirects the output to the **Process.txt** file. The command is submitted to the remote computer, and the file is saved on the remote computer.

```
[Server01]: PS C:\> Get-Process Powershell > C:\test\Process.txt
```

**Exit** command to end the interactive session and close the connection.

```
[Server01]: PS C:\> exit
PS C:\>
```